# Date subtraction returns unexpected result

Tags: javascript, date

I have some JavaScript that pulls dates out of two fields on my web page:

```
var StartDate = document.getElementById('StartDate');
var EndDate = document.getElementById('EndDate');
```

When I get these two dates I have the following snippet of code that performs the date subtraction:

```
var day = 1000*60*60*24;
var d1 = new Date(StartDate.value);
var d2 = new Date(EndDate.value);
var difference = (Math.ceil((d2.getTime() - d1.getTime()) / day))
```

Now is when the problem comes in. Say that my two dates are as such:

```
StartDate = 2013-05-01
EndDate = 2013-06-30
```

Using the calculator we get:

```
1372564800000 - 1367380800000 = 5184000000
5184000000 / 86400000 = 60 days
```

However, next let's use the following dates:

```
StartDate = 2013-10-01
EndDate = 2013-11-30
```

Again, using the calculator we get:

```
1385787600000 - 1380600000000 = 5187600000
5187600000 / 86400000 = 60.04166666666667 days
```

I'm just not sure how this is possible, I am using two identical date ranges. Both start days start on the first of a month with 31 days, and both end days end on the last day of a month with 30 days. When I put these date ranges into a MS Excel workbook I get the correct number of days:

```
=(EndCell-StartCell)
```

And I again get the 60 days for both sets of date ranges.

This seems to only happen when I cross into November of 2013. It doesn't happen when I cross into November of 2014, and I cannot find any other times when this happens. I know 2013 is gone, but my application will deal heavily with 2013 dates. Does anybody know of a reason why/how this is happening? Does anybody know of a better way to do date subtraction with JavaScript that will not cause this issue?

Comment: Things like daylight savings crossovers make doing date math with raw timestamps generally problematic.

Comment: .04166666666667 days is 60 minutes.  So most likely daylight savings. https://www.google.com/search?q=.04166666666667+days+in+minutes

Comment: @dave This doesn't explain why it doesn't happen during DST of 2014.

Comment: It does do the same thing: `(new Date(2014, 10, 15) - new Date(2014, 9, 15)) / (24 * 60 * 60 * 1000)` is `31.041666666666668` (*edit* sorry I retyped that badly instead of c/p from the console)

Comment: @Pointy That's even more strange, as my JS is calculating 2014 dates correctly.

Comment: Note that in the US we go back to standard time on 2 Nov this year, so you have to go more than one day into november to see the effect.

Comment: See the Michael Liu answer to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/542938/how-do-i-get-the-number-of-days-between-two-dates-in-javascript).

Comment: @Pointy The Michael Liu Answer worked perfectly, thank you. Would you make your answer a "top level" answer so that I can mark it up and mark it as the "accepted" answer for my question?